# Taskbar shows over video when focus goes to other monitor

Tags: windows-7, video, multiple-monitors, taskbar, flash

So i have a dual monitor set up and I have a full screened flash video on the main monitor. If I remove the focus from that video to something that is on my other monitor the task bar pops up on top of the video. I would like to know how to disable this WITHOUT auto hiding the task bar.

Answer (score 3):

[DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/) by Binary is a nifty tool for multi-monitor setup:

[image: DisplayFustion Logo]

> DisplayFusion will make your multi-monitor life much easier. With
>   powerful features like **Multi-Monitor Taskbars**, TitleBar Buttons and
>   fully customizable Functions, DisplayFusion will make managing your
>   multiple monitors easy. Take a look at some of the features below to
>   learn how DisplayFusion can help you!

The specific setting that you're looking for can be found by doing the following:

1. Right click on the displayfusion taskbar icon and select "Settings".

   [image: Taskbar Right-Click]
2. Select "Taskbar" on the left side of the setting window:

   [image: Side Menu]
3. Uncheck the "Show task bar in front of full screen application when they lose focus" option

   [image: Options to select/de-select]

This should disable the taskbar in front of the full screen application when it loses focus.

Comment: It doesn't work on the main windows task bar only for the display fusion task bars`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try disabling the notification option and check whether it helps on your scenario.

1. Right click the taskbar
2. Select Properties
3. Click the 'Customize' button in the section labeled 'Notification area'
4. Find the suspect program (Action Center, in my case)
5. Click the drop-down next to the icon of the offending program
6. Select the "Hide icon and notifications" option
7. Click 'OK' to close the Notification Customization screen
8. Click 'OK' to close the Taskbar properties menu

Hope this helps